# Setting up Rails on Hostmonster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server-configuration, hostmonster

I'm able to run `rails s` through ssh successfully and see the app start up just as it does on my own machine but I'm unable to access the app from the web. The app is directly under the home folder and I have a symbolic link pointing from public_html to the public folder of my rails app, just as this [tutorial](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/rails) explains. I even tried setting up a subdomain and every other step in the tutorial to no avail. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Lesson #1 - don't use shared hosting providers for Rails apps ;) You'll be better getting a VPS from [`DigitalOcean.com`](http://digitalocean.com) ^_^ Why? They don't have either the resources or dependency support to create a truly compelling app environment

Comment: How does the shared hosting stop me from accessing the app? I've got the app itself running.

Answer (score 1):

You need an application server like Phusion Passenger, Unicorn or puma to run a Ruby app in a production environment. Typically, you'll integrate the application server into a web server's (Apache, nginx) environment.

I don't know about your hoster, but if you have root access, then you can probably use any of these application servers.

The built-in server you start by running `rails server` is only meant for testing purposes on your local machine. It has not been made with security, performance, stability or any other production-environment criteria in mind.